# How to push project from eclipse to the GitHub

Tags: git

I am using Windows 10.

I have already pushed one of my project from Eclipse to my GitHub account.

When I was trying to push another project, I am having issues on the git repository which already created in my `c:` drive under the name of "`git`" folder.

Now that I already have a git repository folder inside my C drive, it is not letting me browse and choose that repository path for my second project, which I’m trying to push to the GitHub repository.

I’m not good at pushing projects to the GitHub, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to *not* create a Git repository in `C:\git`, but in `C:\git\project1`, `C:\Git\project2`, ...

If you see a hidden folder `.git` in `C:\Git\.git`, and you don't have many commit (but just started), I would:

- remove it
- share your project1 again in Eclipse, but this time making sure the root folder of the repository is create in `C:\Git\project1`.
  See for that "[Share your code in Git using Eclipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-eclipse?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=With%20your%20project%20open%20in,Select%20Finish.)" as an example.
  [image]
- push

From there, Eclipse should let you share other projects.